# Integration of AngularJS and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, angularjs

I have to start a project in AngularJS, Spring and Hibernate. I know Hibernate and Spring but have no idea in AngularJS. Kindly suggest some good links of videos of project development in all AngularJS and Spring from scratch.

Comment: https://egghead.io/  117 video lessons on every moment you want to know in angular

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov thanks for reply but i need videos of integration of spring with angularJs.

Comment: it's quite different parts on your application. There is no such integration as you have with spring+hibernate. You simply use spring to provide rest for your angular. Angular in this case might be on completely different lightweight http server. If you know how to make rest with spring you know how to integrate angular with spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for sample applications in Spring MVC and AngularJS?.Try following Applications which are done using above frameworks combinations.If you are beginner I hope this helps.

You may also [interested in Integration of Spring Security with Spring MVC](http://www.techpages.org/web-frameworks/spring-mvcbootstrap-and-angularjs-sample-applications/2418/)

and

[angular-rest-springsecurity](https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity)

That links helps to Explain good.

Comment: thanks for valuable reply but if you have any link for videos kindly post here